# MissingMethodException after succesfull login to AzureAD

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement AzureAD authentication but I keep getting after successful login
on https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc

> MissingMethodException: Method not found:
> 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityKey
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JwtTokenUtilities.FindKeyMatch(System.String,
> System.String, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityKey,
> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityKey>)'.

Inside the Startup class

```
 services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("MyAdminGroup", policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups", "1204e97b-75fc-498c-a86f-3fc4d36ef4d4"));
            });
```

and appsettings.json is also filled with correct values from Azure portal

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "a4ca2fb4-abad-1ac4-8997-74997a9afb11",
    "ClientId": "b180cc8d-fa37-44b9-af9c-1fa0c7859aad",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
```

On the portal I changed redirect urls to match my .net core app ports to
https://localhost:5001

Comment: What is your MSAL nuget version?https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/ Also are you using any other Microsoft.Identity* nugets? If yes, version? I want to see if any version compatibility issue since the error is surely due to that.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT I don't see that I'm having any Microsoft.Identity.Client reference in the whole project. Does any of these references helps? 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

Comment: Trying to understand what is the current auth library you are using for your asp.net core app. Ideally you should need only one parent nuget Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI (which will automatically install the dependent nugets with correct versions).

Comment: Or you can also look at Micrsoft.Identity.Web (currentl nuget under preview) which simplicies the AAD integration a lot...https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/README.md